# How to clone github respository with python?

Tags: python, api, github

I want to allow user to clone the github repository by providing the url of the repository on their system. I found the api but it didnot work without github credentials. Is their any other way from which i can clone the repository with python without providing the github credentials?

Comment: You could just use `git clone <url>`?

Comment: you have to make your repository public or else [share the repository with them](https://help.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/inviting-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository)

Answer (score 4):

You will have to generate [Git SSH key](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent)
Then you can do something like this:

```
import os
os.system("GIT_SSH_COMMAND=\"ssh -i <insert your git private key here>\" git clone ssh://git@github.com/<username>/<repo>.git")
```

Answer (score 3):

Checkout this library gitpython - 
https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

And below is an example to help you clone

```
import git
git.Git("/your/directory/to/clone").clone("git://gitorious.org/git-python/mainline.git")
```